# Is there an Android Broadcast that announces when the device passcode has changed?

Tags: android

Does anyone know of a way to detect when the password has changed? The key event I would like to capture in my broadcast receiver is when they go from protected with a passcode (PIN, Face, Pattern, etc) to None at all.

When this happens, I want to respond with deleting all the local application data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does anyone know of a way to detect when the password has changed?

A device administrator can find this out, via listening for [`ACTION_PASSWORD_CHANGED` broadcasts](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DeviceAdminReceiver.html#ACTION_PASSWORD_CHANGED) to your active `DeviceAdminReceiver`.

Ordinary apps, AFAIK, do not find out about password changes.